# Most reliable way to execute a function at given times in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time, delay

I need to execute a function at given delays. Let's say I have a vector [0.5,1,0.6], I want the function to be executed after 0.5 second, then after 1 second and finally after 0.6 seconds.

Up to now I've tried a combination of pause(), but the result is way far from accurate and I would like to use pause inside the function, so the handling of my initial offsets (in time) may be cumbersome.

Are there any other possibilities that allow to do this? If there's an error margin of up to 10ms I don't really care.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the timer class: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe create an array of [`timer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timerclass.html) objects in `singleShot` mode, with start times computed from the cumulative sum of the delays:

```
delays = [0.5, 1, 0.6];
startTimes = cumsum(delays);

timerFcn = @(~,thisEvent) disp([thisEvent.Type ' executed '...
     datestr(thisEvent.Data.time,'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF')]);

for ii=1:numel(delays),
    T(ii) = timer('StartDelay',startTimes(ii),'TimerFcn',timerFcn,...
        'ExecutionMode','singleShot');
end
```

Then you can launch all the timers simultaneously:

```
>> start(T); fprintf('Launching timers: %s\n',datestr(now,'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF'))
Launching timers: 21-Mar-2014 12:14:46.780
TimerFcn executed 21-Mar-2014 12:14:47.280
TimerFcn executed 21-Mar-2014 12:14:48.280
TimerFcn executed 21-Mar-2014 12:14:48.880
```

That seems fairly accurate.

Now instead of calling `disp` to print the date and time, launch your function.

**EDIT**: Do NOT forget to delete the timers (`delete(T)`) and/or stop them, especially if the timers are created in a GUI, otherwise they will keep running. Thanks for the reminder, @Daniel.

Comment: Don't forget to delete the timer objects. If the main application should wait until all timers evaluated, `while any(strcmpi(T.Running,'on')),pause(1),end;delete(T)` can delete the timers.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the reminder. In the past, I have neglected this detail when managing a timer in a GUI and it just kept on going and I had to quit MATLAB.

Comment: Note that the accuracy of this may depend on how long the timer callbacks run: while a timer callback (or any handle graphics GUI callback) is running, no other events, including other timers, can fire.